# What's the equivalent of the Gamma function $\Gamma(n+1)$ for $(n+\frac{1}{2})!!$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, gamma-function, frobenius-method

The Gamma function $\Gamma(n+1)$ is equivalent to the factorial function $n!$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It's a generalisation of $n!$ for $n \in \mathbb{\mathbb{R}}$.

In order to build a Frobenius serie, I would like to write someting like $(n+\frac{1}{2})!!$ for $n$ natural, but I can't since in this case $n+\frac{1}{2}$ will never belong to $\mathbb{N}$.

My question is: **Is there a function similar to the Gamma function but for $n!!$** ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial#Complex_arguments FWIW, Maple uses the last definition (with cosine).

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4585497/42969